# Change Virtual PC RAM after creation

Tags: virtualization

I have created a Virtual PC machine and it is running fine. When I created the virtual machine I gave it 1GB of RAM. I now want to up that to 2GB but cannot find a way to do this for an existing machine. The RAM settings seem to be read only when I have it loaded up. Is this possible? I would like to avoid creating a new virtual machine and going through the very long install and updating process just to get the memory updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it, but your VM has to be shut down at the time.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. I shutdown the VM and then when to settings for that machine and it would not allow the RAM setting to be updated.

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: I take it back. I was not shutting it down correctly. I have updated the RAM now.